# Check the state of the checkboxes in an array in Java

Tags: java

I don’t know how to get the state for my checkboxes in an array.
The size of the array will change.

```
public ArrayList<JCheckBox>productCheckboxes = new ArrayList<>();
productsPane = new JPanel();

for(Item i: allItems) {
    productCheckboxes.add(new JCheckBox(p.getName());
}

for(JCheckBox p: productCheckboxes) {
    productsPane.add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JCheckBox class has an `isSelected()` method. That may be what you're looking for.

[Here is the documentation for it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#isSelected())